# Wordpress Delay content being published to non-members

Tags: php, wordpress, membership

I have a wordpress site that uses the WPMU Membership plugin. I want to add code to my template that displays a new post to members 5 days before it is shown to non-members.

Something like this:

```
if (current_user_on_level(17) && CODE TO DETERMINE IF POST IS LESS THAN 5 DAYS OLD) {
echo POST CONTENT; 
}
else { 
echo 'Info not available yet';
}
;
```

What code would I use to determine whether the published post is less than 5 days old??

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. First had to convert the post time to a UNIX code using this code:

(True sets it to UNIX epoch time rather than set to local time zone)

Then I used this code to get the UNIX time 5 days ago

```
strtotime("-5 day")
```

Put the two together with an if statement that displays the content or if it's not time it displays a message that the content isn't available yet.

```
<?php 
$post_timestamp = get_post_time('U', true); 
if (current_user_on_level(17) && $post_timestamp <= strtotime("-1 day")) 
{
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );  
}
else {
echo 'No post available yet <br />';
}?>
```

The only issue with this is that because my posts are ordered in chronological order, the top of my blog is filled with the line "No post available yet". Can anyone think of how I can get these statements to sit at the bottom?